# jQuery Datepicker how to dynamically add IDs to input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form with multiple input fields that use datepicker. I have just created IDs for them and this has worked fine but now I need to use it in an instance where there are multiple forms shown on the same page.

Is there any way to create a jQuery function that will dynamically add an ID to any element with the class of "datepicker" and make the datepicker work on theses elements?

Something like:

```
$('.datepicker').append('ID','datepicker + (1)');
$("#datepicker + (1)").datepicker();
```

I know this will not actually work but I thought it was the easiest way to explain, the +(1) suffixes a number to the ID.

My current code for the static elements works like this.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker01").datepicker();
$("#datepicker02").datepicker();
$("#datepicker03").datepicker();
$("#datepicker04").datepicker();
$("#datepicker05").datepicker();
$("#datepicker06").datepicker();
```

Thanks for the help, cheers :)

Comment: What's wrong with `$('.datepicker').datepicker()`?

Comment: Hi that does work fine but that's with a static page where I've put the IDs in myself. I need it for a page where the script will find all elements with a class of "datepicker" and then add a unique ID and make the datepicker function work on those elements.

Comment: Um, `$('.datepicker')` already selects all elements with the `datepicker` class.

Comment: I know, but I need to dynamically generate the IDs because I wont know how many fields I will need the functions for. It could be for 3 or even 30 fields.

Comment: But what do you need these IDs for?

Comment: This is how the datepicker works, you add an ID to the element, and then target it in the function like so $("#datepicker").datepicker();

Comment: No, the datepicker binds to whatever the selector selects: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ua4bc/

Comment: Whoa! thanks for that, somehow I was under the impression that datepicker worked off of a unique ID. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the IDs at all, you can just bind them all at once with this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ua4bc/

Most plugins can bind to multiple elements at once, that's why almost all of them look like:

```
return this.each(function() { ... });
```

inside.

If you needed the IDs for some other purpose then you could just do this:

```
$('.datepicker').each(function(i) {
    this.id = 'datepicker' + i;
}).datepicker();
```

Demo (use your DOM inspector to see the IDs): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6zfEY/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('class')+parseInt(i+1));
    });

    // You can call like
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker();
});
```

but I think you don't need to add `id`, anyways.

Comment: The top part looks great but is there a way to generate this part: $("#datepicker1").datepicker(); like you did above? Thanks for the help, cheers

Comment: Sorry, what you said about not needing the ID is correct so disregard my last comment thinks

Answer (score 0):

Hello I tried this binding using Spring MVC 3.0 and... 
It works, nice ! I have the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy" });
  });
</script>
```

and then, in my case, working with JSP and JSTL I was able to bind a JQueryPicker to my elements that are created dinamically, and here is a piece of code, if you see a when it's becuase I am working on more things, but the idea is the same:

```
<c:when test="${fieldVar.type == 'DATE'}">
  <td><form:input path="fieldWrapperElements[${status.index}].dateValue"class="datepicker"/></td>
</c:when>
```